# dual port RAM write data

Tags: vhdl, ram

I little bit confused with dual port RAM,my target is write and read data.I want to write data.like on the certain address will be 128 and on the rest adresses will be just 0.Is it works correctly,because Im not sure that those case statements are useful? How to write correctly data in this RAM?
I reading [this](https://www.altera.co.jp/ja_JP/pdfs/...s_qii51007.pdf) article 
and I think I need true dual port Ram.I have next code.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity true_dual_port_ram_single_clock is
 generic (
  DATA_WIDTH : natural := 8;
  ADDR_WIDTH : natural := 6
 );
 port (
  clk : in std_logic;
    addr_a : in natural range 0 to 2**ADDR_WIDTH - 1;
  addr_b : in natural range 0 to 2**ADDR_WIDTH - 1;
  data_a : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
  data_b : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
  we_a : in std_logic := '1';
  we_b : in std_logic := '1';
  q_a : out std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH -1) downto 0);
  q_b : out std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH -1) downto 0)
 );
end true_dual_port_ram_single_clock;
architecture rtl of true_dual_port_ram_single_clock is
 -- Build a 2-D array type for the RAM
 subtype word_t is std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
 type memory_t is array((2**ADDR_WIDTH - 1) downto 0) of word_t;
 -- Declare the RAM signal.
 shared variable ram : memory_t;
  begin
 process(clk)
 begin
 if(rising_edge(clk)) then -- Port A
  if(we_a = '1') then


    ram(addr_a) := data_a;

   -- Read-during-write on the same port returns NEW data
            case addr_a is
            when 0 => 
                 q_a <= "10000000";
            when 16 => 
                 q_a <= "10000000";
            when others => 
                 q_a <="00000000";
        end case;
   q_a <= data_a;
  else
   -- Read-during-write on the mixed port returns OLD data
            case addr_a is
            when 0 => 
                 q_a <= "10000000";
            when 16 => 
                 q_a <= "10000000";
            when others => 
                 q_a <="00000000";
        end case;
   q_a <= ram(addr_a);
  end if;
 end if;
 end process;
 process(clk)
 begin
 if(rising_edge(clk)) then -- Port B
  if(we_b = '1') then
            case addr_a is
            when 0 => 
                 q_b <= "10000000";
            when 16 => 
                 q_b <= "10000000";
            when others => 
                 q_b <="00000000";
        end case;
   ram(addr_b) := data_b;
   -- Read-during-write on the same port returns NEW data
   q_b <= data_b;
  else
   -- Read-during-write on the mixed port returns OLD data
           if(we_b = '1') then
            case addr_b is
            when 0 => 
                 q_b <= "10000000";
            when 16 => 
                 q_b <= "10000000";
            when others => 
                 q_b <="00000000";
        end case;
   q_b <= ram(addr_b);
  end if;
 end if;
  end if;
 end process;
end rtl;
```

Comment: Would be easier to answer if there were a question in your post !

Comment: You do realise that all those case statements are completely redundant, right?

Comment: The main question is,my code work right or not? I want to write data in RAM   in addres 0 and 16,data 128.is it ok now?because Im not sure that my code works correctly

Comment: yes,code work well without those case statements,but I want to write data only in the certain address with certain value

Comment: Define what "work right" means to you. Write that definition as a series of asserts, in VHDL, in a testbench, which also sets up the inputs to test the asserts.. Run the testbench and the asserts will fire whenever it doesn't "work right".  Then you'll have your answer.

Comment: work right its mean that,I write in RAM data like/on the certain addresses for example on the 0 and 16.I write 128.and on the rest of addresses I write zeros